# EC2 Instance Out of the Box

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment

Launching some EC2 nodes, is there anything else I should do before it goes into production?

- Update/Upgrade
- Configured Security Group
- Hardened SSH and changed port
- Installed Anti-Virus for PCI
- Installed Nginx and configured

I know EC2 nodes are simple, but I feel like i'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry about the fact that this is an EC2 instance.

Anything you'd do to secure a physical, dedicated server, you should do here also.

Answer (score 1):

We always like to configure ELB + auto-scaling, to be able to handle unpredicted load. Preferably do it multi-zone to be more protected against outages. And it'd be nice to have a good S3/Glacier backup + disaster recovery policy.